# index match array formula in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, index-match

Can you point me in the right direction for this formula.
I am trying to get a map name for my answer.
I compare the current Eastings and Northings within the array to get a my answer

I have all the array data on a sheet called Map_Data
This is:

```
Map name in col A
Min Easting in col B
Max Easting in Col C
Min Northing in Col D
Max Northing in Col E
```

I can get the formula to work normally in excel, but am having error in VBA.
I think it has something to do with Range.formula as a get a global error

```
Range(ActiveCell).FormulaArray = "=(INDEX(Map_Data!A2:A88,Match(1,(Map_Data!B2:B88<=""" & Eastings & """)*(Map_Data!C2:C88> """ & Eastings & """)*(Map_Data!D2:D88<""" & Northings & """)*(Map_Data!E2:E88>= """ & Northings & """),0),1)"
```

I have played with the input range
That is

`Range("A1").FormualArray`

I want to use the `ActiveCell` instead of `A1`
I have used `Selection.FormulaArray`, but with no luck

Thanks
Roogis

Comment: Looks like you should remove the parenthesis at the start of the embedded formula: `"=(INDEX(Map_Data!A2:...`  => `"=INDEX(Map_Data!A2:...`

Comment: Hi RonI have use Paraenthesis in previous formula. I think it is there to define the formula.

Comment: If remove I get a syntax error

Comment: You seem to have more opens than closes within the quoted formula.

Comment: Hi Ron     Yes thanks one to may parenthesis at the start.  Still get a Method 'Range of object'_Global' failed. So it looks like it can't define the range.  I'll keep playing , catch you later

Comment: Maybe you need `ActiveCell.FormulaArray = ...` instead of `Range(ActiveCell).FormulaArray = ...` because the last is indirect call - address should be in the `ActiveCell` and not the formula.

Comment: As noted by @MGonet, `Range(range_object)` is invalid. `Range(ActiveCell.Address)` would be valid. Or merely `ActiveCell`. But why are you using `ActiveCell` at all. It is rarely necessary and can often cause problems.

Comment: Good Morning Guys.                     If I just use ActiveCell.FormulaArray =.......                I get an error saying  "Can't set FormulaArray Range Class"                                      So back to basics.....           I have various rows and columns in an array, when i get to a particular cell i want this formula  to give me a map name. But I can't specify a cell address like "A1" (or can I ??)  as the macro moves down each row until it gets to Null. So that is why I thought Activecell was the answer.

Comment: Range(ActiveCell.Address) works.        I can see the correct  cell address in debug.            Still can't set the Range class, so must be something a miss in the actual formula.

Comment: *" macro moves down each row until it gets to Null. So that is why I thought Activecell was the answer"*. It isn't. Looping through the range would be more robust. And from what little you've posted I can't tell if the problem is in your formula or your data or your macro. Yours seems to be an [X-Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You think your problem is in the line of code you posted, but it probably is not.

Comment: Yes Ron        There are Do while loops in the code. I have two defined arrays that input two sets of data, one static and one variable, obviously defined in sub routines. The section I am modifying has over two hundred lines of code, so a bit hard to show you.  I definitely know that the issue is in this formula as I have had the program running in the past.   It is only that I wanted a more actuate method of determining a map name based of Eastings and Northings that I made modifications. I understand array  formula in excel,  but not in VBA....hence the question...... Cheers Roogis

Comment: @Roogis You do not provide sufficient information for me to replicate your problem, now that we've straightened out the error in your formula. Perhaps someone else can interpret what you've written and help you. Perhaps you should do the entire calculation in VBA, using native VBA functions, instead of writing formulas to the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion here is that if you're using Standalone purchase of Excel 2019 or later, you can use "xlookup" function using "Worksheetfunction" method.
Also if you try to include this formula to a certain range then, you can use for or for each loop to execute the same.
Thanks!

Comment: Being the quickest gun in the west isn't as important as giving correct answers. Its just a slight oversight. The XLOOKUP function is only available in Excel for Microsoft 365, Excel 2021, and Excel for the web, says it in the support documentation https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929